# Issue Connecting a remote PC to RabbitMQ , WONT CONNECT

Tags: java, netbeans, rabbitmq, remote-access

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;


public class Send {
    
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = " Hello ";
    
    public static void main(String[]argv) throws Exception{
        
     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
     connectionFactory.setHost("rabbitmqPCpublicip");
     connectionFactory.setPort(15672);
     connectionFactory.setUsername("remote");// a new user I created in rabbitmq
     connectionFactory.setPassword("remote");
     
    try( Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();){
     
     channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
     String message = "Hello world";
     channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME ,null, message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
     System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");

}
 
 
    
}
```

}

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
```

// at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:156)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1106)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1021)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1182)
at rabbitmq.Recv.main(Recv.java:31)

Comment: are you certain you have the correct port?

Comment: Yes , this is what shows in the bar after localhost